# no puedo obtener todos los data-files con bs4 con python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando de obtener todos los **data-files** con la libreria **BeautifulSoup** pero no me muestra nada, solo me muestra **[]** en consola

Cómo podria obtener todos?, este es código que estoy usando:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os


url = f"http://localhost/assets.html"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')





data = soup.find_all('data-files')



print(data)
```

este es el codigo html:
[image]

Código html:

```
<div class="assets scrollbar infinite-scroll" data-url="/assets?infinite&amp;category=all-assets" data-offset="1">
    <div class="back-to-top" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">BACK TO TOP</div>
    <div class="asset" data-id="1220" data-title="Fortnite Fracture Logo" data-files="1ka5xLiGmKyU0tc6Ux5XafwN1Kt10daSU;1PhhMBLN6epAMhCQxdBa_Ifvlx3mU-2pV;16ckRFb1AjHLIM9wAhCaL-a3e5gPzDlml" data-likes="17"><img src="/img/assets/icons/1220.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: `find_all("data-files")` buscará todos los **elementos** de ese tipo, pero en tu caso los elementos son `div` y `data-files` es un atributo dentro del elemento. Posiblemente debas usar el parámetro `attrs` de `find_all()`, o escribir una función filtro

Comment: @CandidMoe ya esta disculpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como expliqué en un comentario, `soup.find_all()` espera el nombre de un tipo de elemento, y no de un atributo. En tu caso `data-files` es un atributo. El tipo de elemento es "div".

La forma más simple de quedarte solo con los "div" que tengan el atributo buscado es escribir una función filtro como la siguiente, que recibe un elemento (tag) y devuelve `True` si es uno de los que buscamos:

```
def tiene_data_files(tag):
    return tag.name=="div" and tag.has_attr("data-files")
```

Entonces puedes usar ese filtro como parámetro de `find_all()`, así:

```
data = soup.find_all(tiene_data_files)
```

La lista que recibes como resultado en `data` es la de todos los `div` que tienen el atributo "data-files". Puedes sacar el valor de ese atributo con un bucle como este:

```
for d in data:
    print(d["data-files"])
```

### Todo junto

También puedes usar una comprensión de listas para obtener una lista con los atributos, en vez de con los elementos div. Un ejemplo completo y verificable sería este:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def tiene_data_files(tag):
    return tag.name=="div" and tag.has_attr("data-files")

content = """
<div class="assets scrollbar infinite-scroll" data-url="/assets?infinite&amp;category=all-assets" data-offset="1">
    <div class="back-to-top" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">BACK TO TOP</div>
    <div class="asset" data-id="1220" data-title="Fortnite Fracture Logo" data-files="1ka5xLiGmKyU0tc6Ux5XafwN1Kt10daSU;1PhhMBLN6epAMhCQxdBa_Ifvlx3mU-2pV;16ckRFb1AjHLIM9wAhCaL-a3e5gPzDlml" data-likes="17"><img src="/img/assets/icons/1220.jpg"></div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
data = [d["data-files"] for d in soup.find_all(tiene_data_files)]
print(data)
```

Que produce el resultado

```
['1ka5xLiGmKyU0tc6Ux5XafwN1Kt10daSU;1PhhMBLN6epAMhCQxdBa_Ifvlx3mU-2pV;16ckRFb1AjHLIM9wAhCaL-a3e5gPzDlml']
```